# Как добавить к значению в таблице число по условию в mysql?

Tags: php, база-данных, mysqli

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать скрипт на чистом `php`

Необходим пример подключения к базе данных и в таблице `users` в столбцe `balance` отнимать значение `5` у всех пользователей в том случае, если баланс < 4 то не отнимать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если на чистом php(Без использования PDO), то так(протестировано):

```php
<?php
$servername = ""; // IP Вашей базы
$username = ""; // Имя пользователя mysql
$password = ""; // Пароль пользователя mysql
$db = ""; // Название базы данных
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $db); // Подключаемся

$query = "UPDATE `users` SET `balance` = `balance` - 5 WHERE balance<4"; // Сам запрос.
$q = mysqli_query($conn, $query); // Отправляем запрос.
```

Comment: ПДО - это тоже "чистый" пхп